# Convert json string value into int

Tags: python, json

I want to convert a string value into int from a json.

Json

```
[
    {
        "date": "23.07. 16:59",
        "odd": "3.50",
        "change": "+0.05"
    },
    {
        "date": "23.07. 16:07",
        "odd": "3.45",
        "change": "-0.15"
    }
]
```

I tried to convert in this way `json["change"] = int(json["change"])` but got `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: Your data structure is called 'json' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert `change` to a `float` and not `int`. Iterate over the contents of JSON list and do the conversion.

Here I have converted `change` to `float`.

```
import json
s = '''[
    {
        "date": "23.07. 16:59",
        "odd": "3.50",
        "change": "+0.05"
    },
    {
        "date": "23.07. 16:07",
        "odd": "3.45",
        "change": "-0.15"
    }
]'''

d = json.loads(s)
for i in d:
    i['change'] = float(i['change'])
```

```
[{'date': '23.07. 16:59', 'odd': '3.50', 'change': 0.05}, {'date': '23.07. 16:07', 'odd': '3.45', 'change': -0.15}]
```

Comment: *"You have to convert change to a float and not int."*  is not the real answer to the OP'S question. Their main error was that they did not even parse the JSON in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

**You have to do something like this:**

```
Json=[
    {
        "date": "23.07. 16:59",
        "odd": "3.50",
        "change": "+0.05"
    },
    {
        "date": "23.07. 16:07",
        "odd": "3.45",
        "change": "-0.15"
    }
]
for i in range(len(Json)):
    Json[i]["change"]=int(float(Json[i]["change"]))
```

I guess you want to convert it to float because it will return 0 if you convert to int so you can simply try:

```py
for i in range(len(Json)):
    Json[i]["change"]=int(float(Json[i]["change"]))
```

Comment: The OP has JSON, not a list.